# Circle detection opencv

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, opencv, hough-transform

I Would like an explanation of the parameters for opencv's `HoughCircles` function.

I'm new to image processing in general and I have recently started using opencv. I'm struggling to find circles. I obtained the image below by converting a source image to greyscale then performing a binary threshold.

To my eye, the leftmost images are almost perfect circles. I have seen demonstrations where, what I assume are very noisy and distorted circles have been identified by opencv's hough transform.

[image: Fake Circles according to opencv]

Assuming the image displayed above is saved as "binaryresult.png". If I run the following code I get circles that are poorly placed. I'd like to understand the `HoughCircles` function's parameters so that I can better detect circles.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("binaryresult.png")
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,  2, 32, param1=200, param2=100)

# ensure at least some circles were found
if circles is not None:
    # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

    # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
        # corresponding to the centre of the circle
        cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
        cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)

    # show the output image
    cv2.imshow("output", np.hstack([image]))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with the [Hough line transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform).

The hough transform works by creating a buffer (2 dimensional in our case) which represents all the possible lines in the image.

Any possible line can be represented with those 2 numbers $(\rho, \theta)$

From wikipedia

[image: rho theta]

Note this uses polar coordinates to avoid division by zero issues rather than your typical $y = mx + c$ for a line

The hough transform scans an image and casts votes into the 2 dimensional buffer corresponding to $(\rho, \theta)$ values.

The buffer slots that accumulate the most votes are likely to be attributed to the presence of a line for that $(\rho, \theta)$ value.

That's the basic idea of the Hough transform but it can get more complicated from here.

For selecting $(\rho, \theta)$ values from the buffer, methods can get more sophisticated, such as using [kernel density estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation). Although I don't think opencv does that.

In the case of the [Hough circle transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html), we now have a 3 dimensional buffer. 
$(x, y, r)$

Where

$x, y $:  coordinates of center of circle

$r $: radius

Now in practice there's more to making the Hough transform work than this.

Take a look at the source code for the `icvHoughCirclesGradient` function.

Its [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/7d4d28605087ec2d3878f9467aea313a2acdfd49/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp)

Also `cvHoughCircles` and `cv::HoughCircles`

you can see that the function is also doing [canny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) edge detection and [sobel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) filtering.

These operations have their own input parameters which you can also see as inputs to the hough function.

Examining the function signature

```
void cv::HoughCircles( InputArray _image, OutputArray _circles,
int method, double dp, double min_dist,
double param1, double param2,
int minRadius, int maxRadius )
```

Method: There seems to be only on method now, probably left this for future development

dp: this is the resolution of the votes buffer

min_dist : is the minimum distance between circles (ie: circles that are too close must be part of the same circle)

minRadius and maxRadius are just that.

param1 and param2 are a bit more cryptic

but if you spot the lines

```
int canny_threshold = cvRound(param1);
int acc_threshold = cvRound(param2);
```

You'll see these are related to the canny edge detection and the accumulator threshold for selecting a circle from votes.

Comment: Tweaking the thresholds for edge detection and circle vote threshold will give you different results. Experiment with this along with the other parameters.